# How to give margin to cleared element?

Tags: html, css

How do I give margin to an box respective to a floated box? Here's my source code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
     <head>
         <title>Boxes</title>
         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="intro.css">
    </head>
     <body>
        <div id="page">
            <div id="header">
                <h3 class="welcome">Welcome</h3>
                <h5 class="welcome">to</h5>
                <h1 class="welcome" style="color:green;font-family:cursive">Tamim's</h1>
                <h5 class="welcome">page</h5>
            </div>
        </div>
            <div class="navigation">
                <ul>
                    <li>home</li>
                    <li>photos</li>
                    <li>important-links</li>
                    <li>facebook</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="left">
                <img src="408528_10200574301423959_1609852992_n.jpg">
            </div>
            <div id="right"></div>
            <div id="test"></div>
        </div>
     </body>
</html>
```

and

```
#page{
    min-width:360px;
    margin: 10px auto 10px auto;
    background-color: rgb(32,127,224);
    padding: 20px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px #777777;
    border-radius: 5px;

}
#header{
    width: 360px;
    margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
    text-align: center;
}
.welcome{
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline;

}
#left{
    width: auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
    float: left;
    border: 2px inset red;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: rgb(157,160,146);
    height: 425px;
}
#right{

    float: right;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    border: 2px solid green;
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 425px;
    width: 67%;      

    background-color: rgb(121,241,240);
}
.navigation{
    padding: 1px 3px 3px 3px;
    margin: 20px auto 20px auto;
    width: 500px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}
.navigation li{
    margin: 3px 6px 3px 6px;
    display: inline;
    border: 2px solid black;
    padding: 2px;
    zoom:1;
    width:auto;
}

#test{
    margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: black;
    clear: both;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

[Here's the code on Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/69QKz/1/)

Now when I give top a margin, it is not getting below the left or right? How do I give margin with respect to left? and also why my `#lefts` height is greater than right? But I have given them the same height 425px.?

Comment: NOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO It's Comic Sans NOOOooooOOOO :'(

Comment: How do I add a link? its always telling me links to ... must be acompained by code? I tried 4 space bars,and the hyperlink options, but its always the same.

Comment: _"and also why my #lefts height is greater than right?"_ - your research topic: "box model"

Comment: @TamimAdDari add link here in SO question or in your html page? :D

Comment: thanks for the answer. But I can't really vote up, as my rep is low.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### *Now when I give top a margin, it is not getting below the left or right?*

Because you `clear:both` in the test - footer div. You have to set `margin-bottom` to the left and right see demo.

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/goodfriend/69QKz/14/

### *Why my #lefts height is greater than right?*

It looks like it was caused by the `padding` in the left box.

DEMO with padding in left: http://jsfiddle.net/goodfriend/69QKz/6/

DEMO without padding in left: http://jsfiddle.net/goodfriend/69QKz/5/

**Note:** I also deleted one `</div>` end tag because it was closing the page div after the header..

Comment: I mean that, the top border of the #test is getting aligned with the bottom border of left and right, how do I give space between them?

Comment: that means how do I treat floating boxes same as normal boxes?